# dropdown select with css getting some screen err

Tags: jquery, html, css

I try to make css select box but when I try on firefox I am getting different. but choroe is well. what am i need to put behind the css to show nice screen ?

You can Show on **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4afAE/)**

I put the Print screen for selector error [image: img]

html

```
<label>
    <select>
        <option selected> Select Box </option>
        <option>Short Option</option>
        <option>This Is A Longer Option</option>
    </select>
</label>
```

css

```
body, html {background:#444; text-align:center; padding:50px 0;}

/* The CSS */
select {
    padding:3px;
    margin: 0;
    -webkit-border-radius:4px;
    -moz-border-radius:4px;
    border-radius:4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 0 #ccc, 0 -1px #fff inset;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 0 #ccc, 0 -1px #fff inset;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 0 #ccc, 0 -1px #fff inset;
    background: #f8f8f8;
    color:#888;
    border:none;
    outline:none;
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-appearance:none;
    -moz-appearance:none;
    appearance:none;
    cursor:pointer;
}

/* Targetting Webkit browsers only. FF will show the dropdown arrow with so much padding. */
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
    select {padding-right:18px}
}

label {position:relative}
label:after {
    content:'<>';
    font:11px "Consolas", monospace;
    color:#aaa;
    -webkit-transform:rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(90deg);
    transform:rotate(90deg);
    right:8px; top:2px;
    padding:0 0 2px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #ddd;
    position:absolute;
    pointer-events:none;
}
label:before {
    content:'';
    right:6px; top:0px;
    width:20px; height:20px;
    background:#f8f8f8;
    position:absolute;
    pointer-events:none;
    display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add text-overflow

```
select {
    -moz-appearance: none;
    text-indent: 0.01px;
    text-overflow: '';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select {
-moz-appearance: none;
appearance: none;
text-indent: .03px;
text-overflow: '';
}
```